# render a page that is only requestable 1 time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, render

How would one render a page say a "/logout" page that displays a "Thanks for visiting us" then if the user reloads the browser it would load "/" instead?

I have a

```
match "/logout" => "home#logout"
```

But don't wan't anyone that requesting "/logout" will see this page, it should only be rendered direct after the user is signed_out.

What would be the best way to approach this render a view dependant with a conditional redirect ( to root_path) instead of using a redirect_to

Comment: Are you using any authentication libraries like Devise or Authlogic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
match '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :via => :delete
```

And use `logout_path` in your `link_to` helper or however you decide to implement logging out in your application.

And write your message in the flash in `SessionsController#destroy`. It may look something like:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    sign_out # or whatever you named your method for signing out
    flash[:notice] = "Thanks for visiting us"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

In order to make sure the request goes to `root_path` when the user is not signed in, you should place a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user

  def authenticate_user
    unless signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
  helper_method :authenticate_user
end
```

This way, after the user is signed out, all requests will redirect to `root_path`.

To allow requests to pages without being signed in, use `skip_before_filter` in the appropriate controller classes:

```
def MyPublicStuffsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user
  # ...
end
```